# Активировать бургер при клике по div js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, ul

Всем привет. Имеется бургер-меню, которое раскрывается при клике на сам бургер, который тоже меняет свою форму на вид крестика.

То есть при клике на `.burger` появляется к `.menu` добавляется класс `.open`. Я заключил всё меню в `div.contain`, но при попытке в скрипте вместо `.burger` вставить `.contain` меню активируется, а вот сам бургер в "крестик" не трансформируется.

```js
$(".burger").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $(".menu").toggleClass("open");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contain">
  <!--добавил div-->
  <div class="burger">
    <span id="melt"><span id="extra-melt"></span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#services">Услуги</a></li>
      <li><a href="#advantages">Преимущества</a></li>
      <li><a href="#projects">Проекты</a></li>
      <li><a href="#plan">Порядок работ</a></li>
      <li><a href="#testimonials">Отзывы</a></li>
      <li><a href="#partners">Партнеры</a></li>
      <li><a href="#callus">Свяжитесь с нами</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Как дописать скрипт так, чтобы при клике на .contain и меню активировалось и сам бургер в крестик трансформировался? Плиз хелп

Comment: Я не знаю, как у вас реализовано, но можно сделать так: в burger основной код при клике, а в certain имитировать onclick по burger.

Comment: вешайте на бургер класс .active и при клике по .contain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не привели свои стили, потому добавил свои исходя из вашего JS. И `.burger` лучше делать кнопкой, а не дивом — так не будет нарушаться семантика и доступность элементов.

```js
$(".burger").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $(".menu").toggleClass("open");
})
```

```css
.menu {
  display: none;
}

.menu.open {
  display: block;
}

.burger {
  width: 20px;
  height: 21px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.burger span,
.burger:before,
.burger:after {
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.burger:before,
.burger:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  content: '';
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.burger:before {
  top: calc(100% - 3px);
}

.burger.active span {
  opacity: 0;
}

.burger.active:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 9px;
}

.burger.active:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 9px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contain">
  <!--добавил div-->
  <button class="burger">
    <span aria-hidden=true></span>
  </button>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#services">Услуги</a></li>
      <li><a href="#advantages">Преимущества</a></li>
      <li><a href="#projects">Проекты</a></li>
      <li><a href="#plan">Порядок работ</a></li>
      <li><a href="#testimonials">Отзывы</a></li>
      <li><a href="#partners">Партнеры</a></li>
      <li><a href="#callus">Свяжитесь с нами</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```